# IntelliJ Not Saving Changes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fxml

I've been encountering an issue with IntelliJ. Every time I save a change to some FXML I'm editing, the changes are removed upon executing the program.

[image: Sample Code]

For instance, I will change the 50.0 above into 160.0, and once I run the program the code changes back to 50.0. I've also attached a picture of the project explorer as it may suggest something with Verison Control.

[image: Project explorer]

Evidently some of the colors are not as normal. I imported the project from a Gradle off of a shared GitHub Repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in the `build` folder which contains generated files.

You changed that file, but then it was overwritten. You need to identify the source file and to make that change there if you want to have something persistent.

Comment: Welp, that answered it. Thanks so much, I will now awkwardly retreat.

Answer (score 0):

Running IntelliJ from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1\bin: idea64.exe worked for me.  Now files are being saved and it's not throwing this error.  Navigate to your IntelliJ bin directory above and run IntelliJ from the executable.  You may need to regenerate your short cut file to IntelliJ.